# Rubymotion: how can I access instance variable from inside a mouseDown(event) block?

Tags: scope, rubymotion, mousedown

How should I access instance variable inside the mouse event block?
It does not work even if I call other method from the mouse event definition.

The only way I've found for now is to declare the variable as a class variable, but I don't think this is the right way to follow.

**updated with new code**

app_delegate.rb

```rb
class AppDelegate
  def applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification)

    @view = ViewController.new

  end
end
```

view_controller.rb

```rb
class ViewController < NSView

  def init
    @var = "method called from event"
    loadWindow
  end

  def loadWindow
    @window = NSWindow.alloc.initWithContentRect([[400, 500], [480, 200]],
      styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask,
      backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered,
      defer: false)
    @window.setTitle("Test")

    @cView = ViewController.alloc.initWithFrame([[400,500], [480, 200]])
    @window.setContentView(@cView)
    @window.orderFrontRegardless
    @window.makeKeyWindow
    runEvent                      # <- This puts "method called from event"
  end

  def runEvent
    puts @var
  end


  def mouseDown event
    runEvent                      # <- This puts a blank line
    puts "mouse click"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating two `ViewController` instances, one with `new` and one with `alloc.initWithFrame()`.

`new` is a class method that directly maps to `alloc.init`, thus the `@view` instance is calling `.init` but the `.alloc.initWithFrame()` is not.

The one that is outputting `runEvent`'s contents is the `@view` instance (when it's created) and the one that's outputting the blank line is `@cView`'s instance (`mouseDown`).

You need to set the variable in a common method and then provide an `initWithFrame` method:

```rb
def initWithFrame(frame)
  super
  setVar
  self
end

def init
  super
  setVar
  loadWindow
  self
end

def setVar
  @var = "method called from event"
end
```

Works:

```
method called from event
(main)> method called from event
mouse click
(main)> method called from event
mouse click
```

*Two asides:* Always call `super` in an init method you're overriding, and always return `self`. Also, the way you're loading these `ViewController` classes is kind of weird; it seems like you could move half the code into the `AppDelegate` and avoid this ambiguity altogether.

Comment: thanks, now it's more clear. And I think I really need some more reading on objective c. But I like to get my hands dirty...

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot to learn. Getting your hands dirty / diving in is a great way to learn, if you're also willing to read the docs. :)

Comment: Using rubymotion I was hoping a basic knowledge of Objective C was enough. Obviously I was wrong. Can you recommend some useful reading, in addition to apple class reference?

Comment: I learned a lot from reading the guides that Apple puts out there. [Getting Started](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started) is one place to start. Also, you could read Clay Allsopp's [book](http://pragprog.com/book/carubym/rubymotion). Another great resource is Stanford's iOS courses on iTunes U with Paul Haggerty -- I learned a lot from that series.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an assumption, as you did not provide the full code snippet.

When you have code like this:

```
class SomeController
  @var = "variable"
end
```

You are not creating an instance variable, but a variable on the class level.

This would create an instance variable:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize
    @var = "some value"
  end
end
```

Comment: sure, you are right, I've wrote a very minimal example code.  But it doesn't work either way.

Comment: your code example is not enough to give a better solution. you need to use the initialization method (did you try `init`?) to setup instance variables. instead of an instance variable, you could use a constant or a method.

Comment: is this the same instance? do a `puts self` to have a look

Comment: you mean one `puts self` inside the `loadWindow` and one inside the `mouseDown` ?  Just tried, even with `puts self` only inside the runEvent method.  they are all different instance. Is this the problem?

Comment: is that expected? when you overwrite `init` you are supposed to call `super` like here https://github.com/phoet/chant/blob/master/app/04_controllers/navigation_controller.rb#L5